# how to take snapshot of google map?

Tags: android

I need to take snapshot of google map and save in local database. Please help me to take the snapshot of google map.

Thanks,
Monali

Comment: Press [Print] on your keyboard?

Comment: Can u please tell me how to it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this library http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/ . It runs in background and can allow you to make screenshots without root.

Comment: i downloaded the zip file, can u pls tell me how to integrate this app with my app

Comment: @user437833 You can see the Wiki for the project - http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/DeveloperGuide

Comment: ASL utilizes a native service running in the background, started via the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) once per device boot.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't** make a print screen from inside your app unless the phone is rooted (don't have the code for that).

You can however make a print screen thru the emulator but that not the question here.

For the sake of completeness: 
Emulator printscreen
You have to connect your phone via USB, go to Debug perspective in Eclipse, select the "Devices" tab, select your device in the list and click the "Screen Capture" icon.

Answer (score 0):

Define function in button click event;

```
Button btnCap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTakeScreenshot);
btnCap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            CaptureMapScreen();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

Here is a function `CaptureMapScreen()`

```
public void CaptureMapScreen() 
{
SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bitmap = snapshot;
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/"
                    + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".png");

                // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    myMap.snapshot(callback);

    // myMap is object of GoogleMap +> GoogleMap myMap;
    // which is initialized in onCreate() => 
    // myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_pass_home_call)).getMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void getSnapShot(){
    GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback=new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {

        }
    };
    google_Map.snapshot(callback);
}
```